# Error "X is not a type" even with forward declaration ( c++ )

Tags: c++, forward-declaration

So I'm getting this error "Female is not a type" when compiling, even tho I've tried forward declaring the class Female in the following code:

Male.hpp :

```
#ifndef GUARD_MALE_HPP
#define GUARD_MALE_HPP

#include <Elephant_Base.hpp>
#include <SFML/System/Time.hpp>
#include <SFML/System/Vector2.hpp>
#include <SFML/Graphics/Sprite.hpp>
#include <TextureHolder.hpp>
#include <memory>
#include <Female.hpp>
//class Female; --> doesn't work
class Male : public Elephant_Base {
public:
                    Male();
                    Male(Traits traits);
                    Male(TextureHolder& text, bool hasTusks, age_value a = 0);

    void            update(sf::Time dt);

    void            tryToMate(Female& f); //<--- shows error here

private:
    virtual void    draw(sf::RenderTarget& target, sf::RenderStates states) const;
};

#endif
```

Female.hpp :

```
#ifndef GUARD_FEMALE_HPP
#define GUARD_FEMALE_HPP

#include <Elephant_Base.hpp>
#include <SFML/System/Time.hpp>
#include <TextureHolder.hpp>
#include <memory>


class Female : public Elephant_Base {
public:
                Female();
                Female(Traits traits);
                Female(TextureHolder& text, bool hasTusks, age_value a = 0);

    void            update(sf::Time dt);

    //female methods
    bool            canGetPregnant() const;
    bool            hasChildGrown() const;
    Elephant_Base::Ptr  detachChild();
    bool            isPregnant() const;

private:
    //female functions
    void            drawChild(sf::RenderTarget& target, sf::RenderStates states) const;
    void            makePregnant(const Elephant_Base::Gene& maleGamete);
    void            giveBirth(); //called in update; will create a child

private:
    virtual void    draw(sf::RenderTarget& target, sf::RenderStates states) const;

private:
    //female members
    Elephant_Base::Ptr mChild;
    bool               mIsPregnant;
    age_value          mGestationTime;  

};

#endif
```

I've also tried without forward declaration, I still get the same error, so I'm kinda lost about what should be done here...

EDIT: file Elephant_Base.hpp has been asked, here it is:

```
#ifndef GUARD_ELEPHANT_BASE_HPP
#define GUARD_ELEPHANT_BASE_HPP

#include <SFML/Graphics/Drawable.hpp>
#include <SFML/Graphics/Transformable.hpp>
#include <SFML/System/NonCopyable.hpp>
#include <SFML/System/Time.hpp>
#include <SFML/System/Vector2.hpp>
#include <SFML/Graphics/Sprite.hpp>
#include "TextureHolder.hpp"
#include <memory>

class Elephant_Base : public sf::Drawable, public sf::Transformable {
public:
    typedef float age_value;
    typedef std::shared_ptr<Elephant_Base> Ptr;
    const static sf::Time YEAR_IN_SECONDS_VALUE; //represents the value of a year in a certain amount of seconds
    //enum to define if the Elephant is going to be male or female hence determining the sexual chromosomes
    enum Sex {
        Male,
        Female,
        None,
    };

    //it's actually the sexual chromosomes, but this app aims to study the gene that grows tusks on the elephants
    //Xi is dominant and is the gene that grows tusks
    enum Gene {
        Xi,
        Xi_,
        Y,
        Undefined,
    };

    struct Traits {
        Traits();
        Traits(TextureHolder& text, Sex s, bool hasTusks, age_value a = 0);
        Traits(TextureHolder& text, std::pair<Gene, Gene> g, age_value a = 0);

        Sex                     sex;
        std::pair<Gene, Gene>   genes;
        bool                    tusks, alive;
        age_value               age;

        TextureHolder*          textures;

        static bool hasTusks(std::pair<Gene, Gene> g);
    private:
        //generates random pair of Gene depending on the elephant's sex and tusks
        void                    generateGenes(Sex sex, bool hasTusks);
        //generate random pair of genes depending on sex
        void                    generateRandomGenes(Sex sex);
    };

public:
                Elephant_Base();
                Elephant_Base(Traits traits);
                Elephant_Base(TextureHolder& text, Elephant_Base::Sex sex, bool hasTusks, age_value a = 0);
    virtual        ~Elephant_Base();

    //general methods
    virtual void    update(sf::Time dt) = 0;

    void            setEnclosure(sf::IntRect limits); //sets a limit range in which the Elephant can move
    void            kill();

    bool            hasTusks() const; //returns true if mTraits.tusks = true, hence Elephant has tusks
    bool            isAlive() const;

    sf::FloatRect   getBoundaries() const;
    Traits          getTraits() const;//returns mTraits
    static Gene     randomGeneX();    //returns either Gene::Xi or Gene::Xi_ with equal chances for both

protected:
    //general functions
    void            toAge(sf::Time dt);
    Gene            generateGametes() const; //generates a random Gene amongst owned ones
    void            updateMovement(sf::Time dt);

protected:
    sf::Sprite      mShape;

private:
    virtual void    draw(sf::RenderTarget& target, sf::RenderStates states) const;


private:
    //general members
    Traits             mTraits;
    sf::Vector2f       mMovement;
    sf::IntRect        mEnclosure;  
};

#endif
```

EDIT 2: Some people pointed that Female may have been declared before and indeed I already have a Sex::Female in an enum. So I have to change the name of one of the both.

Comment: Is this the _first_ error message? You should be using `#include "Female.hpp"` if the file is part of your project rather than something installed on the system. Also make sure you have no circular include dependency, e.g. make sure that `Female.hpp` doesn't include `Male.hpp` somewhere.

Comment: It is the first error message I get when compiling the file containing Male functions. I'm going to keep writting the code till it's completed and then I'll if I still get this error. I've change the <> for "" as you advised me to do. I check for circular include and didn't find any

Comment: In that case try to make a [mcve]  from your code, something that we can verify for the error ourselves. With the forward declaration this particular error should not be there, at least as first one.

Comment: I'm going to make a minimal, complete and verifiable example then ;)

Comment: I just tried out by removing #include <Female.hpp> when making the forward declaration, still doesn't work :/

Comment: I also just noticed that (assuming you are using gcc) the particular error message implies that `Female` was declared, but not as a type. gcc gives `Female has not been declared` if the declaration was missing. Did you use the identifier `Female` in any other context somewhere in the translation unit before the inclusion of `Male.hpp`?

Comment: @user10605163 Yes, I wonder if it's finding a declaration of a member of `Elephant_Base`.

Comment: Just posted it! Might be because of my enum Sex that declares a value named Female?

Comment: Okay it's because of the fact that I already have Sex::Female! Just changed the name of the class Female and I dont get the error anymore... Thanks everyone for your time and help!

Comment: You could also do `enum class Sex { Male, Female, None };` as `enum class` doesn't leak its enumerators into the surrounding scope.

Comment: Okay, thanks Oktalist :)